# Solve $x\ln x-x>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$$x\ln x-x>0$$
I have tried to solve it like this.
$$x(\ln x-1)>0\implies x>0\lor\ln x>1$$
Can't define next step. Please help!

Comment: $\ln(x)>1$ so $x>e$

Comment: You can't do inequalities the same way you solve for zeroes. You can set the equation equal to 0 and then draw out a number line with critical points 0 and 1 like you found. From there you can plug in a test point less than 0, between 0 and 1, and greater than 1.

Comment: I think that, when one says "solve the inequality," what is meant is just "find a good concise characterization of the set of $x$ which meet the inequality."  And here's one small additional hint:  if $x<0$ then $\ln x\notin \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

Write it as
$x\ln(x) > x$.

If $x > 0$,
dividing by $x$
preserves inequalities,
and this becomes
$\ln(x) > 1$.
You should be able to solve this.

Since $\ln(x)$ is not defined
for $x < 0$
without using complex numbers,
$x > 0$ is all we have to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach comes close to working. But it isn't true that if $ab > 0$ then either $a > 0$ or $b > 0$; for example, $-1 \cdot -1 > 0$, even though $-1$ is negative. What you *can* say is that if $ab > 0$, then $a$ and $b$ are either both positive or both negative - because positive times positive and negative times negative are both positive.

We have $x\ln{x} - x > 0$. As you observed, we can factor the left, to obtain $x(\ln{x} - 1) > 0$. So either $x$ and $\ln{x} - 1$ are both positive, or they're both negative. But they can't be both negative - if $x$ is negative, $\ln{x}$ is undefined, since the logarithm is defined only on positive numbers. So we know that $x$ and $\ln{x} - 1$ are both $>0$.

The only question left is: when is $\ln{x} - 1 > 0$? Moving the $1$ to the other side, we have $\ln{x} > 1$. Now, $\ln$ is a strictly increasing function - that is, when you plug in bigger numbers, you get bigger numbers out. So once $\ln{x} = 1$, from that point forward (that is, for all larger values of $x$) we have $\ln{x} > 1$. So we just want to know when $\ln{x} = 1$. Using the fact that $\ln$ is the inverse function of $e^x$, we have that $x = e^1 = e$. So $\ln{x} > 1$ whenever $x > e$.

Therefore our final answer is "$x > e$ and $x > 0$". Since $e$ is positive, the $x > 0$ part is redundant, so we can just say "$x > e$". In interval notation, that means that the set of $x$ values satisfying $x\ln{x} - x$ is $(e, \infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

If x=e then A= x(lnx -1)=0 . but lnx is a strictly increasing function. So for 
x < e then A < 0  . and for x> e  then A>0 . So I guess the interval of x's with  x>e is the answer your looking for .